# python plot doesn't display a window

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

When I run this simple code:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

X = [];
Y = [];
for i in range (0,10):
    X.append(i)
    Y.append(i)

plot(X,Y)
show()
```

I don't get any window. I tried to replace `show` with `draw` with the same result.

I'm using python version 3.2.2

How can I show the window/plot than (apart from printing it to file and open the file).

Note, I'm using this example:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think numpy or scipy have a stable release for 3.2 yet.

Unless it's important to you that you use python 3.2, try to install python 2.7 instead. Everything should work fine there.